# Jaeger with webflux and webclient

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient, jaeger, opentracing

Please take a look at https://github.com/winster/jaeger-trace-reactive/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/JaegerTraceReactiveApplication.java (readme might help to understand the problem better https://github.com/winster/jaeger-trace-reactive)

This is a spring boot application with opentracing-jaeger. As per the doc, jaeger supports webflux and webclient. But it has been noted that, the trace skips the reactive flow when there is a webclient call.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem? i'm facing the same problem ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by creating the WebClient in a Bean and not using it directly like this `Webclient.builder().baseUrl(properties.getBaseUrl()).build();`

```
@Bean
WebClient.Builder webClient(){
    return WebClient.builder();
}
```